# Setting an environment variable before a command in Bash is not working for the second command in a pipe

Tags: bash, environment-variables

In a given shell, normally I'd set a variable or variables and then run a command. Recently I learned about the concept of prepending a variable definition to a command:

```
FOO=bar somecommand someargs
```

This works... kind of. It doesn't work when you're changing a `LC_*` variable (which seems to affect the command, but **not** its arguments, for example, `[a-z]` char ranges) or when piping output to another command thusly:

```
FOO=bar somecommand someargs | somecommand2  # somecommand2 is unaware of FOO
```

I can prepend somecommand2 with `FOO=bar` as well, which works, but which adds unwanted duplication, and it doesn't help with arguments that are interpreted depending on the variable (for example, `[a-z]`).

So, what's a good way to do this on a single line?

I'm thinking something on the order of:

```
FOO=bar (somecommand someargs | somecommand2)  # Doesn't actually work
```

---

I got lots of good answers! The goal is to keep this a one-liner, preferably without using `export`. The method using a call to Bash was best overall, though the parenthetical version with `export` in it was a little more compact. The method of using redirection rather than a pipe is interesting as well.

Comment: `(T=$(date) echo $T)` will work

Comment: In the context of cross-platform (incl. windows) scripts or npm-based projects (js or else), you might want to take a look at the [cross-env module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).

Comment: I was hoping one of the answers would also explain *why* this only sort of works, i.e. why it's not equivalent to exporting the variable before the call.

Comment: The why is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998075/setting-environment-variable-for-one-program-call-in-bash-using-env

Comment: Why don't you want to use `export` provided that a side effect is not to pollute your environment? In other words, why does it matter if `export` is used if the variable is not set after the command(s) finish executing. eg: In a subshell.

Comment: In other words: `(export foo="hello")`, `echo $foo` prints a blank line, showing that `foo` is not set outside of the subshell.

Answer (score 490, accepted):

```
FOO=bar bash -c 'somecommand someargs | somecommand2'
```

Comment: This satisfies my criteria (one-liner without needing "export")... I take it there's no way to do this *without* calling "bash -c" (e.g., creative use of parentheses)?

Comment: @MartyMacGyver: None that I can think of. It won't work with curly braces either.

Comment: Note that if you need to run your `somecommand` as sudo, you need to pass sudo the `-E` flag to pass though variables. Because variables can introduce vulnerabilities. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8633575/1695680

Comment: Note that if your command already has two levels of quotes then this method becomes extremely unsatisfactory because of quote hell. In that situation exporting in subshell is much better.

Comment: Odd: on OSX, ```FOO_X=foox bash -c 'echo $FOO_X'``` works as expected but with specific var names it fails: ```DYLD_X=foox bash -c 'echo $DYLD_X'``` echos blank. both work using ```eval``` instead of ```bash -c```

Comment: @mwag: I don't know anything about [`dyld`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker#macOS_and_iOS) ("the dynamic linker"), but it evidently watches for variables that start with `DYLD_` and it recognizes a certain set of them but complains about ones it doesn't know about. The "fails" you refer to is specifically a warning message output by `dyld`: "dyld: warning, unknown environment variable: DYLD_X". Note that that is a warning, not an error, and the value of the variable is actually output.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: I am not invoking ```dyld```, I am invoking ```echo```, and on my system, it does fail: running the exact, verbatim command ```DYLD_X=foox bash -c 'echo $DYLD_X'```, nothing at all gets echo'd (but it does if I use ```eval``` instead of ```bash -c```)

Comment: @mwag: I wasn't invoking `dyld` either. It seems to automagically get invoked. What version of MacOS are you running and what does `bash --version` say? I just checked and the result that I reported above is because I was using Bash 5. When I use `/bin/bash` (Bash 3.2), I get no warning and a blank line is echoed (as if the variable were empty). The dynamic loader is doing something behind the scenes regardless.

Comment: I have asked a [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/358666/48577) about this on apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, thanks for noticing that and asking in the other forum. When I run on 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17) I get a blank, and when I run on 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14) I get the warning + variable.

Answer (score 331):

How about exporting the variable, but only inside the subshell?:

```
(export FOO=bar && somecommand someargs | somecommand2)
```

[Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263) has a point, to unconditionally execute the commands, do this:

```
(export FOO=bar; somecommand someargs | somecommand2)
```

Comment: This appears to work, though it's not quite what I was looking for (it may be that there is no way to do what I'm describing above in one command without explicitly using export first...) Thoughts?

Comment: @MartyMacGyver: `&&` executes the left command, then executes the right command only if the left command succeeded. `;` executes both commands unconditionally. The Windows batch (`cmd.exe`) equivalent of `;` is `&`.

Comment: In zsh I don't seem to need the export for this version: `(FOO=XXX ; echo FOO=$FOO) ; echo FOO=$FOO` yields `FOO=XXX\nFOO=\n`.

Comment: If you have a ton of environment variables and want to load them via a file, you can do that similarly to the above by adding all your `export FOO=bar` settings into a file, then running the above like so: ``(`cat heroku_prod_config` && command some args)``

Comment: @PopePoopinpants: why not use `source` (aka `.`) in that case? Also, the backticks shouldn't be used anymore these days and this is one of the reasons why, using `$(command)` is waaaaay safer.

Comment: So simple, yet so elegant. And I like your answer better than the accepted answer, as it will start a sub shell equal to my current one (which may not be `bash` but could be something else, e.g. `dash`) and I don't run into any trouble if I must use quotes within the command args (`someargs`).

Comment: I have a bash script with a bunch of environment variables exported ie: `export DB_PORT=3306` - I start my program including the env variables like:  `source ./env.sh; ./some-program`

Comment: This is the only answer that works for evaluating the same variables in the command. For example, `(export FOO=foo && echo "$FOO/bar/baz/$FOO")`.

Comment: One circumstance in which a variable assignment would fail and you might not want the command to be executed is if the variable was previously marked read-only.

Comment: I encountered this error (and fix) in `zsh`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208607/zsh-export-not-valid-in-this-context

Comment: If you want to set multiple env, you can run `(export FOO1='bar1'; export FOO2='bar2'; command...)`

Comment: @rampion you sure? `echo` after all, is likely the shell builtin, even in ZSh. So in order to set an actual environment variable you'd still have to export it into the environment. Otherwise it remains a shell variable of some scope (here likely global), but _child processes_ won't see it (terms and conditions apply when we're talking about *subshells*, though ;)).

Answer (score 79):

Use `env`.

For example, `env FOO=BAR command`. Note that the environment variables will be restored/unchanged again when `command` finishes executing.

Just be careful about shell substitution happening, i.e. if you want to reference `$FOO` explicitly on the same command line, you may need to escape it so that your shell interpreter doesn't perform the substitution *before* it runs `env`.

```
$ export FOO=BAR
$ env FOO=FUBAR bash -c 'echo $FOO'
FUBAR
$ echo $FOO
BAR
```

Comment: This is the exactly correct answer, the entire purpose of `env` is to solve the stated question.

Comment: I tested it and it works for me, thanks!

Comment: Using `env` to set vars for a command is kinda pointless if you are in a shell since you can remove `env` from the command and it will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Does this even answer the question? is this answer even correct with its useless use of `env`?

Comment: `env` solves the problem of not overwriting the environment variable in the current shell. But OP wants to run `? cmd1 args | cmd2` and have cmd2 be able to read any environment variables set at `?` which `env` does not solve. And @gniourf_gniourf is right: `env FOO=FUBAR bash -c 'cmd1 args | cmd2'` is functionally similar to `FOO=FUBAR bash -c 'cmd1 args | cmd2'`.

Answer (score 62):

You can also use `eval`:

```
FOO=bar eval 'somecommand someargs | somecommand2'
```

---

Since this answer with `eval` doesn't seem to please everyone, let me clarify something: when used as written, *with the single quotes*, it is perfectly safe. It is good as it will not launch an external process (like the accepted answer) nor will it execute the commands in an extra subshell (like the other answer).

As we get a few regular views, it's probably good to give an alternative to `eval` that will please everyone, and has all the benefits (and perhaps even more!) of this quick `eval` “trick”.  Just use a function! Define a function with all your commands:

```
mypipe() {
    somecommand someargs | somecommand2
}
```

and execute it with your environment variables like this:

```
FOO=bar mypipe
```

Comment: @Alfe: Did you also downvote the accepted answer? because it exhibits the same “problems” as `eval`.

Comment: @Alfe: unfortunately I don't agree with your critique. This command is perfectly safe. You really sound like a guy who once read _`eval` is evil_ without understanding what's evil about `eval`. And maybe you're not really understanding this answer after all (and really there's nothing wrong with it). On the same level: would you say that `ls` is bad because  `for file in $(ls)` is ,bad? (and yeah, you didn't downvote the accepted answer, and you didn't leave a comment either). SO is such a weird and absurd place sometimes.

Comment: @Alfe: when I say _You really sound like a guy who once read `eval` is evil without understanding what's evil about `eval`,_ I'm referring to your sentence: _This answer lacks all the warnings and explanations necessary when talking about `eval`._ `eval` is not bad or dangerous; no more than `bash -c`.

Comment: Votes aside, the comment provided @Alfe does somehow imply that the accepted answer is somehow safer.  What would have been more helpful would have been for you to describe what you believe to be unsafe about the usage of `eval`. In the answer provided the args have been single quoted protecting from variable expansion, so I see no problem with the answer.

Comment: I removed my comments to concentrate my concern in one new comment:  `eval` is a security issue in general (like `bash -c` but less obvious), so the dangers should be mentioned in an answer proposing its use.  Careless users may take the answer (`FOO=bar eval …`) and apply it to their situation so that it raises problems.  But it obviously was more important to the answerer to figure out whether I downvoted his and/or other answers than to improve anything.  As I wrote before, fairness shouldn't be the main concern; being *no worse* than any other given answer also is irregardless.

Comment: A link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead would be enough to hint on the dangers.  A short statement which aspects of the answer make it safe (single quotes, so don't use this without them! or similar) would be even better.

Comment: What I do when someone tells me that my answer lacks some aspect, I don't get at him personally for wanting to know whether they downvoted my answer and whether they also downvoted other answers.  Instead I try to improve my answer.  But we obviously have different approaches on how to handle things.  I find that avoiding communication and editing other people's answers myself is the second best solution because often the original author doesn't even notice this, so I don't know if they agree.  I prefer finding a consensus even if this means to step into the pit.  It just doesn't always work.

Comment: I think the function solution is clearer, though somewhat more verbose, than the `eval` solution.

Comment: `eval` is a very powerful tool. Using it to solve the question here is like using a jackhammer when you need a screwdriver.

Comment: @cambunctious lol, can you please explain what's wrong with `eval`? why is it a jackhammer in this case? why is it worse than the accepted answer that uses `bash -c` (which, is actually worse than `eval` in this case as it spawns a whole new process altogether and exposes exactly the same (supposed) problems as `eval`)? I'm curious to see some genuine arguments beyond “I once read `eval` is evil, and was told to never use it”.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf eval is a very powerful tool in general since it can take any string from anywhere and execute it. Strictly using eval with a single-quoted argument does seem to limit its power/risk, but that is kinda beside the point. `bash -c` also takes any string so indeed it's not much better. To me a subshell or a function is ideal here. I generally dislike writing code in a string literal, but I suppose that is purely aesthetic.

Comment: @cambunctious there's no user input or anything passed to eval, so your point is really moot here, and I also gave a solution using a function.

Answer (score 26):

> A simple approach is to make use of `;`

For example:

```
ENV=prod; ansible-playbook -i inventories/$ENV --extra-vars "env=$ENV"  deauthorize_users.yml --check
```

`command1; command2` executes command2 after executing command1, sequentially. It does not matter whether the commands were successful or not.

Comment: It works because it defines `ENV` in the environment of the same shell in which the commands that follow the semicolon execute.  How this differs from the other answers, though, is that this one defines `ENV` for _all_ subsequent references in the shell and not just those on the same line.  I believe that the original question intended to alter the environment only for the references on the same line.

Comment: adding `;unset ENV` to the same line will make it one liner. but I ignored it as it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Isn't the problem with unset that you may not want `ENV` to be unset? Maybe you want it to have the original value (before `ENV=prod`).

Answer (score 0):

```
some_var="some_value" && echo "${some_var}"
```

Also works. It is similar to:

```
some_var="some_value"; echo "${some_var}"
```

Answer (score -6):

Use a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# myscript
FOO=bar
somecommand someargs | somecommand2

> ./myscript
```

Comment: You still need `export`; otherwise `$FOO` will be a shell variable, not an environment variable, and therefore not visible to `somecommand` or `somecommand2`.

Comment: It'd work but it defeats the purpose of having a one-line command (I'm  trying to learn more creative ways to avoid multi-liners and/or scripts for relatively simple cases). And what @Keith said, though at least the export would stay scoped to the script.

Comment: @KeithThompson Your comment had something new to teach me. I never thought of shell vs environment variables. I used to think of global vs local environment variables. Now I know the correct terminology.