# colour scheme for gnu source-highlight with a dark background

Tags: colors, gnu, color-scheme, source-highlighting

I'm using gnu source-highlight mostly with less (so it's using ANSII terminal codes to make colours). However, with a dark background colour, the highlighted parts are dim and hard to read.

Is there an easy way to tell source-highlight to use a colour scheme more suited to a dark background (as can be done with, for example, [`vim`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Better_colors_for_syntax_highlighting))?

Comment: I suspect it may be possible to setup `LESSOPEN` to pipe stuff through the `vim` highlighter..

Comment: Looks like vim can be used like less: http://superuser.com/a/168284/101005

Comment: The best option for me was [using pygmentize](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19439/how-can-i-display-syntax-highlighting-on-a-file/19440#19440)

Comment: I put this in a bash initialization file
`pygless()
{
  LESSOPEN="| pygmentize -f terminal256 -O style=native -g %s" less "$@"
}`
and I now use _pygless_ to read code :)

Comment: nice one @ricab. Had to change it a bit: `pygless() { LESSOPEN="| pygmentize -f terminal256 -O style=native -g %s"; less "$@"; }` (note the semicolons). Make it an answer and I'll accept it (:

Comment: right @drevicko, I missed the semicolon! Still, only the last one should be there, because I want to use the value of LESSOPEN for the less command. Otherwise, an export would be needed (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10856211/563765))

Comment: indeed! strange, I thought it'd worked before with the extra `;` - perhaps I'd exported it or some such?? who knows! ;)

Comment: Don't know, perhaps you had it already globally set. Also, notice the "-R" that I had forgotten. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to do this with source-highlight, so I skipped it altogether and [used pygmentize](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19439/how-can-i-display-syntax-highlighting-on-a-file/19440#19440) to the same end. For that, I make a function that I use instead of less when I want code highlighting

```
pygless()
{
  LESSOPEN="| pygmentize -f terminal256 -O style=native -g %s" less -R "$@";
}
```

Comment: (in 2019) `pygmentize` is unfortunately very slow:

    `⯈time pygmentize -f terminal256 -O style=native -g < /usr/include/linux/fs.h`
    0,39s user 0,03s system 99% cpu 0,428 total
    `⯈time source-highlight -i /usr/include/linux/fs.h -f esc256`
    0,03s user 0,00s system 98% cpu 0,037 total

edit: ok, so SO comment formatting is still stuck in the 90s