# Setting environment variable for one program call in bash using env

Tags: bash, unix, environment-variables, environment

I am trying to invoke a shell command with a modified environment via the command `env`.

According to the manual

```
env HELLO='Hello World' echo $HELLO
```

should echo `Hello World`, but it doesn't.
If I do

```
HELLO='Hello World' bash -c 'echo $HELLO'
```

it prints `Hello World` as expected (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10856348/1922650) for this info).

What am I missing here?

Comment: A sanity check with no expansion at all is `HELLO='Hello World' env | grep HELLO` which does what is requested but is much less useful in practice than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

It's because in your first case, your current shell expands the `$HELLO` variable before running the commands. And there's no `HELLO` variable set in your current shell.

```
env HELLO='Hello World' echo $HELLO
```

will do this:

- expand any variables given, in this case `$HELLO`
- run env with the 3 arguments  `'HELLO=Hello World'`, `'echo'` and `''` (an empty string, since there's no `HELLO` variable set in the current shell)
- The `env` command will run and set the `HELLO='Hello World'` in its environment
- `env` will run `echo` with the argument `''` (an empty string)

As you see, the current shell expanded the `$HELLO` variable, which isn't set.

```
HELLO='Hello World' bash -c 'echo $HELLO'
```

will do this:

- set the variable `HELLO='Hello World` for the following command
- run bash with the 2 arguments `'-c'` and `'echo $HELLO'`
- since the last argument is enclosed in single quotes, nothing inside it is expanded
- the new bash in turn will run the command `echo $HELLO`
- To run echo `$HELLO` in the new bash sub-shell, bash first expands anything it can, `$HELLO` in this case, and the parent shell set that to `Hello World` for us.
- The subshell runs `echo 'Hello World'`

If you tried to do e.g. this:

```
env HELLO='Hello World' echo '$HELLO'
```

- The current shell would expand anything it can, which is nothing since `$HELLO` is enclosed in single quotes
- run env with the 3 arguments  `'HELLO=Hello World'`, `'echo'` and `'$HELLO'`
- The env command will run and set the `HELLO='Hello World'` in its environment
- env will run echo with the argument `'$HELLO'`

In this case, there's no shell that will expand the `$HELLO`, so `echo` receives the string `$HELLO` and prints out that. Variable expansion is done by shells only.

Comment: +1, Just a nitpick: `env HELLO='Hello World' echo $HELLO` will get expanded to `env HELLO='Hello World' echo` (no args to echo.). `env HELLO='Hello World' echo "$HELLO"` will get expanded to `env HELLO='Hello World' echo ''` (empty string arg to echo.)

Answer (score 5):

I think what happens is similar to [this situation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58397/environment-variable-set-but-not-respected#comment80557_58422) in which I was also puzzled.

In a nutshell, the variable expansion in the first case is done by the current shell which doesn't have `$HELLO` in its environment. In the second case, though, single quotes prevent the current shell from doing the variable expansion, so everything works as expected.

Note how changing single quotes to double quotes prevents this command from working the way you want:

```
HELLO='Hello World' bash -c "echo $HELLO"
```

Now this will be failing for the same reason as the first command in your question.

Comment: Correct.  In the first case, it's the current shell that expands the variable.  In the second case, it's new `bash` being executed that does it.

Comment: Also here many thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately I can only give one answer a nice green tick

Answer (score 3):

This works and is good for me

```
$ MY_VAR='Hello' ANOTHER_VAR='World!!!' && echo "$MY_VAR $ANOTHER_VAR"
Hello World!!!
```

Comment: I don't think this holds to the "for one program call" part of the question. The vars here will stay set for the current session so you'll be able to continue to echo them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easier way to confirm shell is working as expected.

```
env A=42 env
env
```

The first command sets `A` to 42 and runs `env`. The second command also runs `env`. Compare the output of both.

Answer (score 1):

As nos noted, expansion of your variable passed to `echo` occurs before that variable gets set.

One alternative not yet mentioned in the earlier answers is to use:

```
$ a=abc eval 'echo $a'
abc

$ echo $a
<blank>
```

Note that you have to use the `a=abc cmd` syntax and not `env a=abc cmd` syntax; apparently `env` doesn't play nice with the built-in `eval`.