# How to hide tool path variable in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I have a custom tool installed on Linux. Let's call it MyLoggingTool. `which MyLoggingTool` reveals it's located under `~/.local/bin/MyLoggingTool`.

Now I have a build process where I also use this tool but in a different way, I have to use a version located somewhere in a relative path. I cannot prefix the toolname with a path in my scripts as this would make both processes too different.

I would like to hide the toolpath of the installed one with the toolpath to my local version. How would I do sth like that? I tried to just set a variable `called `MyLoggingTool`, hoping it would hide the installed toolpath, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can adjust the PATH variable, which lists the directories to be searched and the order in which they're to be searched

Comment: Yes, I could try that, but this is more of a temporary thing. Is there a way of doing that just for the current process?

Comment: Yeah, each process has its own `PATH` variable

Comment: You can set the `PATH` variable separately for the build script, or for a particular window, etc. If you're familiar with Python, that's how virtualenv works

Comment: OK, so I could just try ```ùnset``` I guess. But when I do a ```env | grep MyLoggingTool```, then I actually don't get any reference to my tool, it's located in a central bin folder but not actually in my ```PATH``` variable (sorry I'm not a Linux guy...)

Comment: Yes, the executable's name won't be in your `env`. The path to it `~/.local/bin` will be in `$PATH`.

Comment: Just set the `PATH` variable inside your build script (or inside a wrapper script); then the script will use the modified path but it won't affect anything outside

Answer (score 1):

Ref.
[How to set an environment variable only for the duration of the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128542/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-only-for-the-duration-of-the-script?noredirect=1&lq=1)
and [Setting environment variable for one program call in bash using env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998075/setting-environment-variable-for-one-program-call-in-bash-using-env)

You may alter the PATH definition specifically for your tool execution in the same mood such as:

```
$ PATH=~/.local/bin/MyLoggingTool:$PATH MyBuildTool
```