# passing command line argument to python-behave

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

I am using python-behave for BDD testing, I have to pass an URL (e.g. www.abc.com) from command line.

```
$behave -u "www.abc.com"
```

To achieve this, I have read [behave documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/behave.html#configuration-files) but there are not enough materials as well as explanations given for setting up the behave.ini file. I am also not sure how behave.ini file helps me to pass an argument.

Can someone please tell me how I can setup command line parameters for behave?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The command line arguments should be passed on the command line when you run `behave`. What is it about that isn't clear? Are you trying to run `behave` from some other code? What is it that you want to put in the `ini` file?

Comment: i just want pass a url from command line, like: $behave --url "www.abc.com" and use this url to environment.py file within a method 
def before_all(context):
    context.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    context.url = "www.abc.com"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Outdated answer,**
Currently supported itself as described by  this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28638924/538284).

No, it's not possible, because there is a `parser` that is [defined](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/77ebf779452a826601f21629f4351027f3639dda/behave/configuration.py#L421) in `configuration.py` file, and only [allow](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/77ebf779452a826601f21629f4351027f3639dda/behave/configuration.py#L492) defined [options](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/77ebf779452a826601f21629f4351027f3639dda/behave/configuration.py#L56) of it.

But if you want you can (by help of monkey patch !), just add your option same as other options to this `parser`.

For do that, first create a file for example `behave_run.py` and patch this `parser` before running of `behave`:

```
from behave import configuration
from behave import __main__

# Adding my wanted option to parser.
configuration.parser.add_argument('-u', '--url', help="Address of your url")

# command that run behave.
__main__.main()
```

And now if you run `python behave_run.py --help`, you can see your new `url` option:

```
$ python behave_run.py --help | grep url
  -u URL, --url URL     Address of your url
```

Now, you can run this `behave_run.py` file like `behave` file and pass your url argument too:

```
$ python behave_run.py --url http://google.com
```

And you can access this value of `url` option with `context.config.url`, for example in `environment.py` file and then set it for use in other functions:

```
def before_all(context):
    context.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    context.url = context.config.url
```

*Note:*

If you want to call `python run_behave.py` as `run_behave.py` from anywhere, add this line:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

to first line of `run_behave.py` and change mode of it to a executable file with `chmod +x run_behave.py` and then copy this file to one location of your `PATH`, for example in `/usr/local/bin` with `sudo mv run_behave.py /usr/local/bin/run_behave.py`

Comment: I think as of `behave-1.2.5` @jenisys answer should be the accepted one - it's a clean implementation of the above.

Comment: ***This answer is outdated***. Keep scrolling to see the much, much nicer method for doing this posted by @jenisys.

Answer (score 34):

The suggested solutions above were needed in the past.

behave-1.2.5 provides a "userdata" concept that allows the user to define its data:

```
behave -D browser=firefox ...
```

**SEE ALSO:** [behave: userdata](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5.html#index-7)

Comment: @user3375505 imho this should be the accepted anser

Comment: Reference link in this answer needs update: https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/behave.html?highlight=user%20data#cmdoption-define

Comment: One tradeoff with this answer is that you cannot use `--help` to discover the supported parameters. Patching the `parser` would add arguments and documentation to `--help`. How do you recommend documenting or making userdata options discoverable?

Answer (score 5):

As jenisys said, the way to pass user data is:

```
behave -D NAME=VALUE
```

An the way to access it from behave steps files is:

```
context.config.userdata['NAME']
```

Comment: Do you know whether it will take multiple key-value pairs?

Comment: Hi Vreddhi!, yes, you can use -D option in command line to pass in as many user data as possible.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the great answer by Omid, would be to set environment variables before your call to behave, something like:

`TESTURL="www.abc.com" behave`

There are caveats to doing this and some examples of different scopes/permanence of the variables you would be defining in some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856129/setting-an-environment-variable-before-a-command-in-bash-not-working-for-second)

Comment: If you're going this route, you'll also need to know [how to access environment variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4906977/1417451)—TL;DR: `os.environ['FOO']`.