# How to start node server and export NODE_PATH (with npm start or inline command)

Tags: node.js, shell, command-line, npm, package.json

Before starting the server, I need to export ('set' actualy, I'm using Win7) NODE_PATH variable. I tried to do it with this command (not working even in command line):

```
set NODE_PATH=./ && node server.js
```

and for package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_PATH=. && node server.js"
  },
```

But it's not working. I got `Error: Cannot find module` which appears only if `NODE_PATH` not specified.

So, how this problem could be solved? I need a proper way to export `NODE_PATH` and run the server with **inline command**, or a way to **specify two separate** commands for 'start' script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> set NODE_PATH=./ ***;*** && node server.js

On Windows, the command above works fine. And in general, it should work without a semicolon when you set environment variables. But here, probably, path string causes the problem?

Also notice that you should set environment variables in a different way for Linux, no `set` keyword must be used. If your scripts will be run on a different platform, probably it's better to use some plugin like [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) to write your scripts.

This question helps [Setting an environment variable before a command in Bash is not working for the second command in a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856129/setting-an-environment-variable-before-a-command-in-bash-not-working-for-second)

Answer (score 1):

Below is what worked for me in Linux (CentOS). I needed this because the node modules in use were all installed globally.

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules && node myscript.js"
},
```

Use **export** instead of **set**. No semicolon needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
NODE_PATH=./ node server.js
```

without set and ;
tested on bash