# A bash function to act as an alias to directory of executables?

Tags: bash, zsh

I found it hard to come up with a suitable title. Here's what I'd like to have:

`$ some_prefix deploy`

Should run an executable called `deploy` in `/some/directory/somewhere` where I can substitute "deploy" for any other executable in that directory. I could add `/some/directory/somewhere` to my PATH, but some of the scripts have generic names so I'd like to call them with a prefix.

Comment: You should be able to use a function or shell script to accomplish this.

Comment: which OS are you on? (or do you want a portable solution?).   I think  on OSX, 'some_prefix' would be 'open'.

Comment: You could always just use store the directory in a variable and do something like `$some_prefix/deploy`.

Comment: @Kevin yes I'm looking for help writing said function. Storing the prefix in a variable sounds like a fine idea, but I'd to be able to invoke `prefix deploy` at the prompt, rather than `$prefix/deploy` although thats pretty close

Comment: This just sounds like a function with a hard-coded path in the body.

Comment: @philwalk i'm on mac os. `open` is not what i'm looking for - the requirement is that i simply don't want to have to type out the full path to run those executables.

Comment: @chepner yes! can you provide an example of such a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want a function that hard-codes a path:

```
run_it () {
    "/some/directory/somewhere/$1" "${@:2}"
}
```

Then call

```
run_it deploy foo bar baz
```

to run

```
/some/directory/somewhere/deploy foo bar baz
```

Comment: You should use shift if you do not want to run `/some/directory/somewhere/deploy deploy foo bar baz`

Comment: @waltera: or: `"/some/directory/somewhere/$@"` :-)

Comment: @rici That always makes me squirm for some reason. :)

Comment: @chepner: if you're going to code in bash, you need to learn to control your squirm reflex.

Comment: Try `cp /bin/echo "/some/directory/somewhere/my echo"; run_it "my echo" "Hello"`

Answer (score 1):

Make a function or alias called `setmy`, that will set a lot of alias functions based on the list of executables in `/some/directory/somewhere`.
Your `setmy` will perform `alias mydeploy=/some/directory/somewhere/deploy` for all executables.
Next call your function with prefix `my`, only skip the space:

```
mydeploy
```

Comment: this is a better solution than what i was going for

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily redefine the value of `PATH` by prepending its definition to the command:

```
PATH=/some/directory/somewhere:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin deploy
```

This can also be packed into an alias:

```
alias some_prefix='PATH=/some/directory/somewhere:$PATH'
```

So that you only need to run:

```
some_prefix deploy
```

The shell (`bash`, `zsh` or even `dash`), will first expand the alias

```
PATH=/some/directory/somewhere:$PATH deploy
```

and then the `PATH` parameter

```
PATH=/some/directory/somewhere:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin deploy
```

before using the redefined `PATH` to search for the `deploy` command *and* also passing it onto the environment of the `deploy` process.

---

**Note:** The definition is scoped only to the following command, **not** to the whole command line. So, if you run

```
some_prefix deploy ; deploy
```

only the first `deploy` will be searched in the modified `PATH`, while the second uses the original value of `PATH`. The same holds true for commands that are chained with `|`, `&&` or `||`. If that is an issue, you might want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10856129/2992551). Of course it is always possible to just use the alias multiple times as needed:

```
some_prefix deploy; some_prefix deploy
```

Comment: cool! i would have thought that the def would be scoped to the whole session. good trick to know. makes sense though now that i think about it. `export` would make it session wide right?

Comment: @DustMason Not exactly. If you just define a parameter on the command line without an added command, e.g. `NAME="VALUE"`, it already is scoped to the whole shell session. `export NAME` is only needed, if you want to make it available in the environment of any subsequent external commands started from that session. `export NAME="VALUE"` is just a shorthand that combines both. But `NAME="VALUE" command` is different in that it defines `NAME` only in the environment of `command`, it does not affect the running shell session in any way. Also, `export NAME="VALUE" command; command` will not work.