# Pass environment variable to multiple commands

Tags: shell, unix

When I do

```
Hello=123 npm run a && npm run b && npm run c
```

I was expecting `Hello=123` environment variable to be passed inside `a, b and c` process. But it turns out only `a` has the environment variable correctly set.

Is there any other ways that I can pass parameters all at once?

Comment: Which shell are you using? The answer might depend on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting an environment variable before a command in bash not working for second command in a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856129/setting-an-environment-variable-before-a-command-in-bash-not-working-for-second)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
Hello=123 sh -c 'npm run a && npm run b && npm run c'
```

Better: use `env` before the whole line. This makes the one-liner work in both Bourne/POSIX and csh-derived shells:

```
env Hello=123 sh -c 'npm run a && npm run b && npm run c'
```

Your observation is that `var=val foo && bar` sets `$var` only in the environment of `foo`, not `bar`. That's correct. The solution is to set the environment for a command that in turn runs `foo` and `bar`: `sh -c`.

The other solution, of course, is simply:

```
Hello=123; export Hello   # or export Hello=123 if using bash
npm run a && npm run b && npm run c
```

Comment: The last solution is cleanest, and if you want it even more clean, wrap it in parentheses so the exported variable is available only where it needs to be.

Comment: The first one can work. The last one `Hello=123` pollutes my environment though.

Comment: Agreed, I don't like the env clutter either. But the previous comment about wrapping in parentheses solves that.

Answer (score 0):

I simply use `export`.

```bash
export FOO=bar && npm run a && npm run b && npm run c
```