# Start Xdebug session for Symfony CLI commands

Tags: php, symfony, xdebug, symfony-console

My dev setup includes PHP 8 and Xdebug 3 in a docker container for a Symfony project.

Currently I use `xdebug.start_with_request=yes`, but I don't like the performance impact that has.

How do I start an Xdebug session on demand for Symfony console commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Xdebug mode to `off`(`xdebug.mode = off;` in your settings), set the environment variable `XDEBUG_MODE = debug` only for the script you are executing:

```shell
XDEBUG_MODE = debug bin/console run:my:command
```

Now Xdebug will only be enabled while you execute `bin/console run:my:command`.

You mention that you are executing your scripts inside a docker container, but that shouldn't change things too much. You could pass the environment variable in the `docker exec` call with the `--env` argument.

Comment: thanks @yivi! Setting the `XDEBUG_MODE ` manually is probably the best i can do. But it actually should be `XDEBUG_MODE=debug bin/console run:my:command` (without ;)

Comment: Fixed it for you. When the env vars are actually populated or not is something that can be confusing sometimes. I had better luck with `;`, and I'm [not the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856129/setting-an-environment-variable-before-a-command-in-bash-is-not-working-for-the). I guess it depends exactly what are you running and where do you need the env var to be available.