# How to "exec" with "DISPLAY"?

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, unix

I am trying to do

```
exec("DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0 foo")

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0 foo
    from (irb):1:in `exec'
    from (irb):1
    from :0
```

How to fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
exec("env DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0 foo")
```

Learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7128542/368167).