# How to access dynamic variables in expression in YQ

Tags: json, yq

How to use dynamic variables in expression

myres.txt

```
[
{
"name": "test-001",
"is_preconfigured": true,
},
{
"name": "my-connector",
"is_preconfigured": 3
},
{
"name": "checkerfrom_default2_002",
"is_preconfigured": false,
}
]
```

When i use direct command
`yq e '. | .[].name | select(. == "my-connector")' myres.txt`
This gives me result as `my-connector`

But when I use following way
NAME_IN_YAML="my-connector"

```
EXISTING_NAME=$(yq e '. | .[].name | select(. == $NAME_IN_YAML)' myres.txt)
```

This is blank result

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) use the [`env(..)` function](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators#read-string-environment-variable) to load environment variables from the shell, i.e.

```
NAME_IN_YAML="my-connector" yq e '.[].name | select(. == env(NAME_IN_YAML))' myres.txt
```

Note that, if you are using `yq` version [above 4.18.1](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1), the eval action `e` is the default one and can be skipped altogether.

---

If you are looking to format/manipulate JSON text, you should probably consider using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) which has loads of features to use.

Comment: @DnyaneshwarJadhav: You didn't run the command as I told in the answer. `NAME_IN_YAML="my-connector"` has to be set in the same line as the `yq` command and not before. See [Passing environment variables to a process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183403/5291015)

Comment: Hey I got your point now, I was doing it in two different lines, this was causing my problem. I am able to get the results, thanks for your help and patience to understand deeply. :)