# Setting up process.env variable from package json script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I want to set process.env.ENV as TEST or null using a script from package.json but below command is not working via package.json (it works when I run it directly on cmd.).

`script {
    "start": "cross-env ENV=null && node app.js",
    "test": "cross-env ENV=TEST && istanbul cover mocha test"
}`

I am using [corss-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to use a common syntax for setting up env variable for Windows and Linux.

Running `set ENV=TEST` or `set ENV=null` before `npm start` or `npm test` work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need && in scripts

try

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env ENV=null node app.js",
  "test": "cross-env ENV=TEST istanbul cover mocha test"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Further, what commands need && and what not?

Comment: you use && when you need to run second command after the first ran successfully. Setting env variable before running command like above itself is not really a command, so no need to use &&. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128542/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-only-for-the-duration-of-the-script