# python fabric: set environment variable

Tags: python, fabric

I have a question that is somehow covered by documentation but I simply do not understand it.

I want to start a flask app and set two shell environment variables first:

```
export FLASK_APP=startup.py
export DEBUG=1
pipenv run flask db upgrade
```

In fabric I run the second command:

```
run("pipenv run flask db upgrade")
```

But It eludes me on how to set the environment variables. I read all the examples but I dont understand them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of what is talked about in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56444/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-command-line-and-have-it-appear-in-c) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128542/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-only-for-the-duration-of-the-script)

Thus:

```
run("env FLASK_APP=startup.py DEBUG=1 pipenv run flask db upgrade")
```